# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION - How do I turn off the Integrity checks?

Tags: field-integrity-exception

I am getting the error "There's a problem with this state, even though it may appear correct. Please select a state from the list of valid states.: Shipping State/Province" when creating an order in Salesforce. The errors are coming from Mexico and Colombia where the spelling of the state does not match what is in the pick list for Salesforce.

For Mexico I pre-processed my address to convert to what is expected in Salesforce for example:

```
Distrito Federal => Federal District
Estado De México => Mexico State
```

However, I don't know all the possible combinations and don't want to manually add pre-processing standardization each time a new integrity issue shows up.

Can I turn off the integrity checks for specific countries?

For Colombia, I got the error because the state "Bogotá D.C." did not exist in the pick list for Colombia. However as you can see below, there is no states or state codes defined for Colombia, so why would I get this integrity error?

I'm looking for what is the correct way of dealing with this type of situations.

[image]

Comment: I've used this [open-source tool](https://github.com/mattandneil/statecodes) to populate all states/provinces that I've needed.  Otherwise, you have to enter manually, or completely deactivate State Country Picklist.

Comment: [related issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122863/state-country-picklists-importing-leads-with-states-for-countries-without-st?noredirect=1#comment527151_122863) which I see you have already commented on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot turn off State/Provence / Country integrity checks.

This integrity check occurs *before* the trigger is fired.  (trust me, I spent several months on this issue with an integration between SF and a Marketing Platform).

All you need to do is get a list of all the state / countries and see what doesn't match up.

Then create a map of the 'wrong' data to the 'right' data, you then can create a vlookup field (in excel?) to map the data correctly and then use those fields for your import.

Comment: happy to give you detailed instructions if you need it... how are you doing the import.

NOTE you can't do this in your object trigger... it is tooooo late.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will add the states as they come up until I can build a more automated solution for this.